# How can I evaluate the content of an expression language variable in the Eclipse debugger?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, debugging, jakarta-ee, el

I am using Eclipse and I have the following problem debbugging a JSP page.

So into a JSP page I have something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${listaScuoleDS}" var="scuola" varStatus="item">
    ................................................
    ................................................
    DO SOMETHING
    ................................................
    ................................................
</c:forEach>
```

So, as you can seem in the **forEach** cycle I am using the **expresion language** that identify a collection on which iterate:  **items="${listaScuoleDS}"**

Now, starting the application in debug mode and putting a brackpoint on the previous  statment, the application correctly stop on this line but I can't analyze the content of the **"${listaScuoleDS}"** variable.

I try to put **"${listaScuoleDS}"** into the Ecipse **expression** debug tab but I obtain no value.

How can I see the content of the previous EL variable in debug mode?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not debug tags bound to taglibs inside JSP-Files.

Answer (score 0):

There's an implicit object called `pageContext`. You should be able to access this variable through your debugger. I have noticed that this method may not work in `IntelliJ` but it does work in `Eclipse`.

In `Eclipse`:
Open Debug Perspective and write 'pageContext' in the Expressions window.

Here are a couple reference:

[Page Context Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jspapi/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html)

[`pageContext` Example](https://www.javatpoint.com/pageContext-implicit-object)